# How to implement a periodical page refresh with a failover

Tags: ajax, jsp, prototypejs

I am trying improve the fault tolerance in a JSP-page that is updated on a periodical basis. A timeout is used to keep track of when it is time to submit the page.

Problem is that the communication regularly fails which leaves us with a broken/missing page that won't refresh when the communication is up and running again.

The code below is the current implementation.

```
function startTimer(buttonid) {
    var startstring = 'myTimer("' + buttonid + '")';
    window.setTimeout(startstring,15000);
}

function myTimer(buttonid) {
   window.document.forms[0].submit();   
}
```

startTimer() is called in the onload event of the page.

```
<body onload="startTimer('blurp');
```

Best solution is a page that gracefully degrades when the communication is down. In that case it emits an error message and tries to refresh after a set period again.

I was looking at PeriodicalUpdater in Prototype as a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Why not making a Asynchronous post request using javascript? That way it can be easily made to degrade gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a fake div to store the result of the ajax request, when you get a response then update the real div, when you get an error of communication than do nothing or signal to the client that the data in that div is old

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater($('fakeUpdateDiv'),
                   url, {
                     frequency : 30,
                     method : 'get',
                     parameters : {
                    },
                onSuccess : function(transport) {
                  $('realUpdateDiv').update(transport.responseText);
                },
                onFailure : function(transport) {
                              //do something
                }
            });
```

**PS**: the `fakeUpdateDiv` is set to `display:none`

Comment: This was the embryo to the solution. To get it to work as planned I added a check for readyState==4 and status==200.

Comment: can you put your solution up please?